# How to create a payment_intent with subscription Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to build a payment flow for my customers where when they go to a checkout page for a product I give them an offer to subscribe to the app and get a discount on the product.
So I create a payment_intent for the product on the backend and send the secret to the frontend to create the payment element. This is my code:

```
$paymentIntent = $stripe->paymentIntents->create(
                    [
                        'setup_future_usage' => 'off_session',
                        'customer' => 'customer_id',
                        'currency' => 'usd',
                        'amount' => '4999,
                        'automatic_payment_methods' => [
                            'enabled' => 'true',
                        ],
                    ]
                );
return $paymentIntent->client_secret;
```

When a user clicks a button on the checkout page to get a subscription a call is made to the backend where I create a new subscription in stripe and append the stripe price of the product to the subscription->create data. Then from the latest invoice I obtain the payment_intent for the subscription + product and send back the secret to refresh the payment element. This is my code:

```
$subscriptionStripe = $stripe->subscriptions->create([
            'customer' => $customer,
            'items' => [
                ['price' => $planEntity->getStripePaymentLinkMonthly()],
            ],
            'payment_behavior' => 'default_incomplete',
            'add_invoice_items' => [['price' => $price]],
            'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
            'trial_end' => $trial_end,
        ]);


        $invoice = $stripe->invoices->retrieve($subscriptionStripe->latest_invoice->id);

        $client_secret = $stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve($invoice->payment_intent)->client_secret;
```

My subscription has a trial period and when I use this payment flow the user is charged for the product but when it comes time to charge him for the subscription he needs to go and verify the 3ds code and payment fails. If I remove the trial period the user is charged for both the product and subscription and everything works fine.

Can I achieve this with trial period?

Also when I am doing things this way I create a payment_intent for the product initially which then remains incomplete. Is there a way to update the initial payment_intent for the product to include an invoice for a subscription?

Any other suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thank you

I tried to pay the initial payment_intent for the product first and then off_session to pay the invoice for the subscription but I got the error that the user needs to verify the card with 3ds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Stripe APIs support linking a PaymentIntent with an existing subscription really. Ideally, you should only be creating a PaymentIntent when the customer is ready to checkout (after they make their choice of subscribing OR not subscribing). That way you can either create a one-off PaymentIntent OR a subscription with trial & [one-time charge](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#first-invoice-extra)

The alternative here would be for you to collect PaymentMethod details prior to creating a PaymentIntent or Subscription using [the new deferred PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred?type=payment) flow.